# Interpolate arbitrary value between columns with Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, regression, interpolation

I have records containing a 'DaysFrom' column, and additional columns containing values for a standard set of 'DaysFrom':

```
'Date'      'DaysFrom'  '90'    '180'   '360'
2023-11-04   135         4       5       12
2023-11-05   360         3       5       20
2023-11-06   270         5       7       15
2023-11-07   180         6       3       10
```

I want to calculate a linear interpolation ('IntVal') for the value in the 'DaysFrom' column:

```
'Date'      'DaysFrom'  '90'    '180'   '360'   'IntVal'
2023-11-04   135         4       5       12      4.5
2023-11-05   360         3       5       20      20
2023-11-06   270         5       7       15      11
2023-11-07   180         6       3       10      3
```

For ease of calculation the above example only uses 'DaysFrom' values that fall on a column or halfway between two columns, but 'DaysFrom' can be any arbitrary value between 90 and 360.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to interpolate using all values (in case they are not all on a straight line), you can loop over the rows with [`numpy.interp`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html):

```
import numpy as np

cols = df.columns[2:]
tmp = df[cols]

df['IntVal'] = [np.interp(df.loc[i, 'DaysFrom'], cols, tmp.loc[i])
                for i in df.index]
```

Output:

```
         Date  DaysFrom  90  180  360  IntVal
0  2023-11-04       135   4    5   12     4.5
1  2023-11-05       360   3    5   20    20.0
2  2023-11-06       270   5    7   15    11.0
3  2023-11-07       180   6    3   10     3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a linear interpolation conditionally based on the `DaysFrom` range:

```
import numpy as np
first_h = (df.DaysFrom - 90) / 90 * (df['180'] - df['90']) + df['90']
second_h = (df.DaysFrom - 180) / 180 * (df['360'] - df['180']) + df['180']

df['IntVal'] = np.where(df.DaysFrom < 180, first_h, second_h)

df
#         Date  DaysFrom  90  180  360  IntVal
#0  2023-11-04       135   4    5   12     4.5
#1  2023-11-05       360   3    5   20    20.0
#2  2023-11-06       270   5    7   15    11.0
#3  2023-11-07       180   6    3   10     3.0
```